# modal working on firefox and IE but not chrome

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

not sure why my modal not working in chrome. upon click only the background showing faded and chrome dev tool load before and after at the same time with no content in between.

codepen here:
codepen.io/tnguyenbco/pen/BLjGbV

i link the modal body with another HTML on click it load and pop up

CSS as below:

```
.modal{background:rgba(45,160,224,0.95);}
.modal-dialog{width:auto;
margin:0;}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog, .modal.in .modal-dialog {transform: none;}
.modal-backdrop.in{opacity:0;}

#myModal .modal-content {
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
box-shadow: none;
padding: 81px 0;
background:none;
color:#ffffff;

}

.modal-title{margin-bottom:16px;
font-weight:700;}

.exit-modal{
font-size:48px;
text-align:right;
line-height: 1;
margin-bottom:24px;}
```

and html to link the modal is

```
<a href="service-1-modal.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Comment: Codepen/JSFiddle for this please. I don't even know if it's bootstrap or foundation (lack of experience in both).

Comment: So what is the JavaScript that is showing the modal? Are you using a framework?

Comment: give me one second let me put it on codepen

Comment: without knowing the context, the first thing I notice is without content there is no height set on the modal, maybe you content is in the modal?

Comment: i link the modal body in another html file.

Comment: http://codepen.io/tnguyenbco/pen/BLjGbV

Comment: Not sure if it is make anything clear but chrome dev tool saying this  `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out. seem like chrome is blocking cross origin requests when i link my own modal from an external html file. Tested with heroku and it's working.

Thanks all